# Execute code at the end of Apex session

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Similar to the onClose() handler in other languages, can I execute code in Apex right before the session terminates? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide more description? What do you want to achieve? I understood that you want to execute some code before smth ends. Can you describe this 'something'?

Answer (score 1):

There's no supported way to do this, if you only care about UI sessions then you may be able to hack something up with a homepage component.